# CodeIgniter URL issue

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am having difficulty getting the correct URL when I call a method to load a view.

Heres my controller:

```
public function post() {
        $title = $this->input->post('title');
        $data = $this->p_Model->post($title);
        $this->qs($data);
    }

public function qs($id){
        $title = $this->s_Model->getTitle($id);
        $result = $title->result();
        $this->load->view('q_View', array('results' => $result));
    }
```

Heres my view:(note this view is not the view which gets loaded from the `qs` function, but one which calls the `qs` function)

```
<html>
<body>
<table>
<?php
        if (isset($qs)) {
            foreach ($qs as $row) {
                $id = $row->qID;
                echo '<a href="'.site_url('myController/qs/'.$id).'">';
                echo $row->title;
                echo "<br>";
            }
        }
?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

So in my controller I have two functions, the `qs` function works separately by itself so can be called in the view and give the following url `myController/qs/1` however when I use the post function I get a url like this `myController/post` so my question is how can I get my url to be like the first example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the line:

```
$this->qs($data);
```

You can use a redirect:

```
redirect('/mainController/qs/'.$data);
```

That should work in the same way that you have used in your view

Answer (score 0):

Try [base_url](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html) and also you can use `current_url()` returns the full URL (including segments) of the page being currently viewed.

```
echo '<a href="'.base_url('myController/qs/'.$id).'">';
```